# Seeking 1-band raster colour table workaround in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, legend, color

Does anyone know what the workarounds are for the 1-band raster colour table plugin in QGIS?

Currently I find it will run once, then crash on the second iteration. The workaround I use is to delete the two files which the plugin creates in the directory of the raster - *.aux.xml and *.bccPAL1. After this I find I can run the tool again.

Both Wroclaw and trunk.

But is there something I am overlooking, a simpler workaround?

Answer (score 2):

It is a 3rd party plugin, so it cames with "no warranty", but I agree that it would be nice to have it fixed. You can contact the author and see if it is interested in doing it, otherwise if you known python you can try to fix yourself (and so do a favour to many people). If don't know python and the QGIS apis and the author has abandoned it, you can always ask someone with the necessary skills to have it fixed (and so make a favour to many people).